# best way to convert an array of strings to a vector?

Tags: java, arrays, vector

As the title suggests, what is the best method for converting an array of strings to a vector?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you're using a Vector instead of an ArrayList?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Call the constructor of Vector that uses an existing collection (your array, in this case) to initialize itself:

```
String[] strings = { "Here", "Are", "Some", "Strings" };
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(strings));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Vector<String> strVector = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(strArray));
```

Breaking this down:

- `Arrays.asList(array)` converts the array to a `List` (which implements `Collection`)
- The `Vector(Collection)` constructor takes a `Collection` and instantiates a new `Vector` based off of it.
- We pass the new `List` to the `Vector` constructor to get a new `Vector` from the array of `String`s, then save the reference to this object in `strVector`.

Comment: So i can straight up do String[] myArray = {"hello", "world"} and then just throw in Arrays.asList(myArray) in the constructor of the Vector?

Answer (score 3):

```
new Vector(Arrays.asList(array))
```